# Getting PANIC: could not open file "pg_wal/0000000100000038000000DE": Operation not permitted in production. How to solve this?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, corruption

We are getting below mentioned logs in our production postgresql 10 database. We faced a downtime due to the same error and postgresql wont start. We re-initialized the data directory, restored the backup and resolved the downtime. But after the activity, we are getting similar logs and looks like we might face downtime again.

```
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.220 PST @ 5171 0:2024-01-18 00:36:14 PST ] ERROR: could not open file "global/6100": Operation not permitted
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.222 PST @ 31329 0:2024-01-13 12:35:25 PST ]LOG: worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 5171) exited with exit code 1
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.242 PST postgres@database 9040 24963135:2024-01-17 23:26:30 PST 172.0.0.68(59910)]FATAL: could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.m
ap": Operation not permitted at character 13
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.243 PST @ 28561 0:2024-01-17 15:12:17 PST ]PANIC: could not open file "pg_wal/0000000100000038000000DE": Operation not permitted
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 31329 0:2024-01-13 12:35:25 PST ]LOG: WAL writer process (PID 28561) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 31329 0:2024-01-13 12:35:25 PST ]LOG: terminating any other active server processes
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 11887 0:2024-01-18 00:44:02 PST ]WARNING: terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 11887 0:2024-01-18 00:44:02 PST ]DETAIL: The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 11887 0:2024-01-18 00:44:02 PST ]HINT: In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 11908 0:2024-01-18 00:44:03 PST ]WARNING: terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 11908 0:2024-01-18 00:44:03 PST ]DETAIL: The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST @ 11908 0:2024-01-18 00:44:03 PST ]HINT: In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST postgres@database 15050 0:2024-01-17 23:33:25 PST 172.0.0.68(48510)]WARNING: terminating connection because of crash of another server process
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST postgres@database 15050 0:2024-01-17 23:33:25 PST 172.0.0.68(48510)]DETAIL: The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
[2024-01-18 00:44:36.245 PST postgres@database 15050 0:2024-01-17 23:33:25 PST 172.0.0.68(48510)]HINT: In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
[2024-01-18 00:47:43.021 PST postgres@database 19909 0:2024-01-18 00:47:43 PST 172.0.0.68(43480)] FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
[2024-01-18 00:47:43.021 PST postgres@database 19908 0:2024-01-18 00:47:43 PST 172.0.0.68(43478)]FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
[2024-01-18 00:47:43.021 PST postgres@database 19910 0:2024-01-18 00:47:43 PST 172.0.0.68(43482)]FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
[2024-01-18 00:47:43.157 PST @ 31329 0:2024-01-13 12:35:25 PST ]LOG: the database system is ready to accept connections
```

This is a VM, and the disk have enough space. How can we solve this? Does this look like an issue with the disk itself?

Comment: That looks like a software problem to me. Do you have something, for example an anti-virus program, that blocks access to files? What is your operating system? Do the files exist?